# Snoopy tripping up on https?

Tags: php, web-crawler, snoopy

Running a simple php web crawler via Snoopy - http://turma.sourceforge.net/web/urlator/snoopy.html - but the Fetchlinks() function is having a bit of an issue. Normally fetchlinks() grabs all the links on a page and slots them nicely into an array. This is working fine for all http:// links, but any https:// links are tacked on to http:// links, and aren't put in their own slot in the array.

Example of broken https links:

[472] => http://www.vapetropolis.ca/returns/https://www.vapetropolis.ca/product-warranties [473] => http://www.vapetropolis.ca/vaporizer-parts/davinci-vaporizer/https://www.vapetropolis.ca/product-warranties/https://www.vapetropolis.ca/customer/account/

As you can see, they're tacked on to properly formed http:// links.

This is the code that produces this

```
    function crawl_link($link, array &$sitewide_link_list) { 
        $snoopy = new Snoopy;
        //Get all links from first page
        $snoopy->fetchlinks($link);
        $currPage = $snoopy->results;

        //Add all links to global array
        //First, filter the links
            //Ensure all links are from correct domain

        $parsedDomain = 'www.vapetropolis.ca';

        if (is_array($currPage)) {

            foreach ($currPage as $link) {
                if ($parsedDomain == parse_url( $link, PHP_URL_HOST )) {                
                    if (!in_array($link, $sitewide_link_list)) {
                        array_push($sitewide_link_list, $link);
                    }   
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //Start crawl

    //Global array of links
    $sitewide_link_list = array();
    $checkList = array();
    $done = false;


    $domain = 'http://www.vapetropolis.ca';

    crawl_link($domain, $sitewide_link_list);



    print_r($sitewide_link_list);
```

Any clue what might be going on?

Comment: Did you ever  find an answer?  I'm having similar issues.